# PyTest Suppress Results Debug Statement

Tags: pytest

I am using PyTest with the following options: `-s`, `-v`, and `--resultlog=results.txt`. This suppresses print statements from my test, but prints the test names and results as they are run and logs the results to `results.txt`.

However, if any tests fail, I also get a spew of information containing traceback, debug, etc. Since I am logging this to a file anyway, I don't want it printed to the screen, cluttering up my output.

Is there any way to disable the printing of just these debug statements, but still have it logged to my results file?

**Visual example:**

Currently, I see something like this:

```
$ py.test -sv --resultlog=results.txt test.py
=============================== test session starts =========================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- /...
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /Users/jdinkel/Documents, inifile:
plugins: profiling-1.1.1, session2file-0.1.9
collected 3 items

test.py::TestClass::test1 PASSED
test.py::TestClass::test2 PASSED
test.py::TestClass::test3 FAILED

===================================== FAILURES ==============================
__________________________________ TestClass.test3 __________________________
self = <test.TestClass instance at 0x10beb5320>

    def test3(self):
>     assert 0
E     assert 0

test.py:7: AssertionError
========================== 1 failed, 2 passed in 0.01 seconds ===============
```

But I would like to see this:

```
$ py.test -sv --resultlog=results.txt test.py
=============================== test session starts =========================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- /...
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /Users/jdinkel/Documents, inifile:
plugins: profiling-1.1.1, session2file-0.1.9
collected 3 items

test.py::TestClass::test1 PASSED
test.py::TestClass::test2 PASSED
test.py::TestClass::test3 FAILED

========================== 1 failed, 2 passed in 0.01 seconds ===============
```

With no change to the `results.txt` file.

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to do this, but you could probably do so with a plugin.

Comment: you can redirect it using `py.test > results.txt`

Answer (score 13):

You should use `tb` switch for controlling traceback.

e.g.
`pytest tests/ -sv --tb=no --disable-warnings`

`--disable-warnings` disable occasional pytest warnings which I assume you don't want either.

From pytest help:

> --tb=style            traceback print mode (auto/long/short/line/native/no).

Comment: Voted this answer up since it suppresses the detailed printing of source code that failed, which seems to be what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of @SilentGuy, `-r N` suppresses the summary of failed testcases.